# Pgfplots does not seem to be able to do the calculations right

Tags: pgfplots

Something is wrong. I have a more or less complicated equation that I want to plot. I done it with pgfplots and with Excel just to compare. In the first picure below you can see that the curves are totally different, but they shouldn't be. In the second picture I have commented out part of the equation and it looks better, but it is not the whole equation. Why is this?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,   xmax=15,
    ymin=0,   ymax=6000,
        height=9cm,
        width=9cm,
        grid=major,
    ]
        
    \addplot[domain=0:15, blue,  thick]  {-181+5239*sin(1.27*atan(0.164*(1+1.61)*(x-0.126)
                           +( atan(0.164*(x-0.126)) )  % <-- commented in second picture
                            )))};
    \addlegendentry{pgfplots}

    \addplot coordinates {
            (0, -675.65)
            (1, 2800.72)
            (2, 4384.31)
            (3, 4880.72)
            (4, 5024.89)
            (5, 5057.21)
            (6, 5051.86)
            (7, 5033.73)
            (8, 5011.89)
            (9, 4989.81)
            (10, 4968.78)
            (11, 4949.26)
            (12, 4931.33)
            (13, 4914.91)
            (14, 4899.89)
            (15, 4886.14)
    };
    \addlegendentry{excel}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Results:**

[image]

**Results with part of the equation commented**

[image]

Comment: what is exactly the function you want to plot?

Comment: As it is now, it is not possible to know exactly what you are doing wrong. One thing is the mismatched parentheses, -but where to put them!? an other thing could be be that excel according to this: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sin-function gives the trig function in radians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to tell, what the correct result should be, but here is one way to make the plots the same: -delete one parentheses from the end and switch to radians:

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,   xmax=15,
    ymin=0,   ymax=6000,
        height=9cm,
        width=9cm,
        grid=major,
        trig format plots=rad,
    ]       
    \addplot[domain=0:15, blue,  thick]  {-181+5239*sin(1.27*atan(0.164*(1+1.61)*(x-0.126)
                           +( atan(0.164*(x-0.126)) )  % <-- commented in second picture
                            ))};
    \addlegendentry{pgfplots}
    \addplot coordinates {
            (0, -675.65)
            (1, 2800.72)
            (2, 4384.31)
            (3, 4880.72)
            (4, 5024.89)
            (5, 5057.21)
            (6, 5051.86)
            (7, 5033.73)
            (8, 5011.89)
            (9, 4989.81)
            (10, 4968.78)
            (11, 4949.26)
            (12, 4931.33)
            (13, 4914.91)
            (14, 4899.89)
            (15, 4886.14)
    };
    \addlegendentry{excel}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two similar plots in same graph]

Comment: That is great, it is correct now! Thanks alot. Strange that it worked with excel, perhaps it ignored the parentheses.